# iframe to access local page from remote

Tags: javascript, iframe

I work on PLC programming and supervisors.

My plant is composed of: supervisor, one or more PLC, modem for remote access.

- The supervisior has 192.168.2 ip address
- The PLC has 192.168.3 ip address
- The modem has 192.168.1 ip address
- The local PC has 192.168.4 ip address

Setting the function "port forward" correctly on the modem, i can access on the supervisor web pages from my office. The supervisor web pages are composed by me in javascript.

The PLC has a integrated web server and i can access for a local PC.
The problem is that accessing the PLC remotely is impossible (function blocked by the PLC supplier)

On a supervisor i made a page with an iframe with this code:
`<iframe style="width: 1024px; height: 540px" name="external" src="192.168.1.3/index.htm"/>`

In this way I can integrate the PLC web pages into the supervisor web pages.

These pages, however, are visible from the computer connected to the local network. 
From remote PC doesn't work.

How can i change the iframe to view this page also from remote?
Thanks!

Here the image of my plant
https://i.stack.imgur.com/t07OB.png

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

An iframe just gives the browser a URL. If there is no network route between the browser and the server hosting the URL then it can't access it.

---

You could add more port forwarding to expose the other site, but this has some really worrying implications about security.

Instead, you should consider setting up a Virtual Private Network and disabling the port forwarding.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use an easier way to read and write to the PLC via Ajax.

There is an open source project called LECPServer, you can use this middleware to read and write PLC content through the HTTP POST protocol.

code like this:

```
// send
{
    "action": "plc_read_node",
    "node": "NODES.MODBUS.C0000"
}

// response
{
    "errcode": 0,
    "errmsg": "",
    "rtval": [
        true,
        true,
        false,
        false,
        false
    ]
}
```